# How to check particular target path is exist in url rewrite management magento?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I have few custom urls in magento url rewrite management. I need to check whether a particular target path exists in the url rewrite management. For example, if my target path is "XXXX/YYYY/XYZ", how would I check that this target path is present in the url rewrite management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite` model, e.g. like this:

```
$oUrlRewriteCollection = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->getCollection()
//  ->addStoreFilter($iStoreId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('target_path', 'XXXX/YYYY/XYZ');

if (count($oUrlRewriteCollection) > 0) {
    // target path does exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did the exact need.